# Delphi multithread with ado freezing problem

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ado

in the code below im creating some buttons on an empty form..
each button starts a thread on its click, that connects to sql and opens some queries. which works fine..
while a thread is working clicking the same button suspends it. and clickling again resumes it. which also works just fine..

once i start spamming random buttons, the program freezes and neihter returns to normal nor
gives an error.. i just couldnt figure whats wrong with it..

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, IdThread, Winapi.ADOInt, ActiveX,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.SyncObjs, System.Threading, Vcl.Buttons,
  Vcl.AppEvnts, Vcl.ComCtrls;

const
  CnnStr = 'write your connection string here';
  OpenCmnd1 = 'write a query that returns some result. ie: "select * from xxx"';

type
  TMyButton = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton)
    OwnedThread: TThread;
    ProgressBar: TProgressBar;
  end;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
    private
      FCounter: Integer;
      FCountTo: Integer;
      FProgressBar: TProgressBar;
      FOwnerButton: TMyButton;
      FConnection: TADOConnection;
      FQuery: TADOQuery;
      procedure DoProgress;
      procedure SetCountTo(const Value: Integer);
      procedure SetProgressBar(const Value: TProgressBar);
      procedure SetOwnerButton(const Value: TMyButton);
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
      destructor Done;
      property CountTo: Integer read FCountTo write SetCountTo;
      property ProgressBar: TProgressBar read FProgressBar write SetProgressBar;
      property OwnerButton: TMyButton read FOwnerButton write SetOwnerButton;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject) ;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;
var
  Form2: TForm2;
  allThreads: array of TMyThread;

implementation
  {$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean) ;
begin
  inherited;
  FCounter := 0;
  FCountTo := 100;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Done;
begin
  inherited;
  FQuery.Close;
  FreeAndNil(FQuery);
  FConnection.Close;
  FreeAndNil(FConnection);
end;

procedure TMyThread.DoProgress;
var
  PctDone: Extended;
begin
  PctDone := (FCounter / FCountTo) ;
  FProgressBar.Position := Round(FProgressBar.Step * PctDone) ;
  FOwnerButton.Caption := FormatFloat('0.00 %', PctDone * 100) ;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
const
  Interval = 1;
var
  aThreadID:integer;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    FProgressBar.Max := FCountTo div Interval;
    FProgressBar.Step := FProgressBar.Max;
    FProgressBar.ShowHint := True;
    FProgressBar.Hint := 'Thread ID ='+IntToStr(GetCurrentThreadID);
    aThreadID := GetCurrentThreadID;
    if not Assigned(FConnection) then
    begin
      FConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
      FConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
      FConnection.ConnectionString := FORMAT(CnnStr,[GetCurrentThreadID]);
      //FConnection.ConnectOptions := coAsyncConnect;
    end;
    if not FConnection.Connected then
      FConnection.Open;
    if not Assigned(FQuery) then
    begin
      FQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
      FQuery.Connection := FConnection;
      FQuery.SQL.Text := OpenCmnd1;
      FQuery.ExecuteOptions := [];
      FQuery.ParamCheck;
    end;
    while FCounter < FCountTo do
    begin
      if FQuery.State = dsBrowse then
        FQuery.Close;
      FQuery.Open;
      if FCounter mod Interval = 0 then Synchronize(DoProgress) ;
        Inc(FCounter) ;
    end;
    FOwnerButton.Caption := 'Start';
    FOwnerButton.OwnedThread := nil;
    FProgressBar.Position := FProgressBar.Max;
  finally
    CoUnInitialize;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SetCountTo(const Value: Integer) ;
begin
  FCountTo := Value;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SetOwnerButton(const Value: TMyButton) ;
begin
  FOwnerButton := Value;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SetProgressBar(const Value: TProgressBar) ;
begin
  FProgressBar := Value;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject) ;
var
  aButton: TMyButton;
  aProgressBar: TProgressBar;
begin
  aButton := TMyButton(Sender) ;
  if not Assigned(aButton.OwnedThread) then
  begin
    allThreads[aButton.Tag] := TMyThread.Create(True) ;
    aButton.OwnedThread := allThreads[aButton.Tag];
    aProgressBar := TProgressBar(FindComponent(StringReplace(aButton.Name, 'Button', 'ProgressBar', []))) ;
    allThreads[aButton.Tag].ProgressBar := aProgressBar;
    allThreads[aButton.Tag].OwnerButton := aButton;
    allThreads[aButton.Tag].Resume;
    aButton.Caption := 'Pause';
  end
  else
  begin
    if aButton.OwnedThread.Suspended then
      aButton.OwnedThread.Resume
    else
      aButton.OwnedThread.Suspend;
    aButton.Caption := 'Run';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 5 do
  begin
    with TMyButton.Create(self) do
    begin
      Parent := Self;
      Tag := i;
      Left := 10;
      Top := 10 + 30*i;
      width := 100;
      Caption := 'Button'+IntToStr(i);
      Name := 'Button'+IntToStr(i);
      onClick := Button1Click;
    end;
    with TProgressBar.Create(self) do
    begin
      Parent := Self;
      Tag := i;
      Left := 120;
      Top := 12 + 30*i;
      width := 200;
      Name := 'ProgressBar'+IntToStr(i);
    end;
  end;
  SetLength(allThreads,6);
end;

end.
```

this is just a demo to represent my problem.. sorry for the coding.

Answer (score 2):

First, you *must* synchronize with the UI thread when accessing UI controls from a worker thread (ie, when updating your progress bars, etc). You already have a `DoProgress()` method for that purpose, but you are not using it.

Second, `Suspend()`/`Resume()` are dangerous when misused, that's why they are *deprecated*. If you want to suspend a thread *safely*, you need to **ask the thread to suspend itself** when it is safe to do so. You can't just blindly suspend a thread externally whenever you want, you don't know what state the thread is in at the time, and if it's inside a lock or synchronize, etc then bad things *will* happen (as you are finding out).

After fixing the UI sync issue, the simplest solution to the suspend issue is to add a boolean to your thread class and set it to true when you want to suspend the thread, and then have your thread's `Execute()` method look at that boolean periodically and call `Suspend()` on itself only when it is not doing something else.

Comment: The real question is why is there a need for suspending a thread? What is the required functionality.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar In this particular example, probably none. But there are valid (albeit rare) use-cases for suspending threads. Thread Pooling, for instance (though, there are better ways to implement that).

Comment: Exactly what you said. Even if there is a need to "pause" a thread there are more appropriate ways to do so than using Suspend.